# "Null is returned from a method that is expected to return a non-null value" with cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios10

Under iOS 10, this new warning gets thrown.

What is the appropriate way to return from cellForRowAtIndexPath in the cases when the method cannot determine the appropriate cell to return (e.g. exceptions)?

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView == self.selectedContentTableView) {
        // make cell...

        return cell;
    }
    else if(tableView == self.recipientTableView) {
        // make cell...

        return cell;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Some exception message for unexpected tableView");

        return nil; // ??? what now instead
    }
}
```

Comment: You really should know if **you** designed more than two table views. ;-)

Comment: Maybe...  but I really *shouldn't* know everything any coder adds after me. ;)

Comment: *Any coder after you* is responsible for himself.

Comment: This is not new to iOS 10.  One has never been allowed to return `nil` from `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`  If it's not outright crashing, _that_ might be new.  And bad.  It should crash.

Comment: @vadian So if my car is leaking a pool of oil on the highway, I can say drivers after me are responsible for themselves? No, this would be sloppy thinking -- trying to make a gray area black or white. I am partly responsible and they are partly responsible. I am responsible for delivering on business requirements AND reducing total cost of ownership to the best of my ability. That includes making decisions that enable future work on the system, by myself or others, to be as effective and efficient as possible.

Answer (score 5):

If that situation is a *programming error* which should not occur,
then the appropriate action is to terminate the program with an error
message, so that the programming error is detected and can be fixed:

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView == self.selectedContentTableView) {
        // make cell...

        return cell;
    }
    else if(tableView == self.recipientTableView) {
        // make cell...

        return cell;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Some exception message for unexpected tableView");
        abort();
    }
}
```

The `abort()` function is marked with `__attribute__((noreturn))`,
therefore the compiler will not complain about a missing
return value.

Comment: There is also `fatalError` that combines `abort` and `NSLog` and also prints the file and line number.

Comment: @Sulthan: There is `fatalError()` in Swift. Does it exist in Objective-C as well?

Comment: Oh right. I am so used to read swift questions. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

There is no appropriate value to return because the situation is 100% programmer error.  It's best to write code for the expected situations (different tableviews, different cell types based on model data, etc.) and let any unhandled cases fall through and return `nil` naturally.  Checking for such cases just compounds the error by intentionally hiding it.

Apple's philosophy regarding exceptions in Objective-C is that they are used to signal programmer error.  `UITableView` throwing an exception when `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` returns `nil` is UIKit's way of telling you that you've made a mistake in your logic.  Fix the mistake, don't paper it over.

Comment: I don't think that OP wanted to "paper it over". On the contrary, he *had* `return nil;` in his code, which would cause a runtime exception. The problem is that with the new nullability annotations, the static analyzer complains on `return nil;`. That's why I suggested abort().